# how to get Goliath::Runner instance port in Goliath?

Tags: ruby, argv, goliath

I am trying to grab server's port **outside** a request controller in Goliath, which means I cannot access `env['SERVER_PORT']`.

So I tried to parse `ARGV`, turns out it's empty

I found there's a `port` property of `Goliath::Runner`, but how to refer to the current runner instance in Goliath?